# How to call a function from another pageview class to another in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, inherited-widget

I need help calling a method of another class in a pageview. I have an app which has a pageview consisting of two classes, Page 1 and Page 2 respectively. Both of them are stateful widgets.

I am trying to call a method from Page2 from Page1, but it is difficult for me as both of them do not have a child/parent relationship so I could not use a callback function. In fact, both of them are a child of another parent class (MainParent). I tried using globalkey but i received currentState is null error.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
class MainParent extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
   MainParentState createState() => MainParentSate();
}

class MainParentState extends State<MainParent> {

  PageController pageController;

  @override
  initState(){
    pageController = new PageController(
  }

  List<Widget> _showPageList(AppModel appModel){
     List<Widget> pageList = new List();
     pageList.add(Page1(/*some named parameters pass here*/));
     pageList.add(Page2(/*some named parameters pass here*/));
     return pageList;
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
              physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: pageController,
              onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
              children: _showPageList(),
        )
     );

   }
}
```

Page 1 class

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
   Page1State createState() => Page1State();
}

class Page1State extends State<Page1> {

  _callPage2Function(){
     //animate to page 2 and mount it
     MainParent.of(context).pageController.animateToPage(
      1,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
      curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);

     //this doesn't work
     Page2State page2state = new Page2State();
     page2state.refreshList();

     //creating a global key doesnt work as well, gets currentstate is null
     GlobalKey<Page2State> page2Key = new GlobalKey<Page2State>();
     page2Key.currentState.refreshList();
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
           child: GestureDetector(
             onTap: () => _callPage2Function()
           )
        )
     );

   }
}
```

Page 2 class

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
   Page2State createState() => Page2State();
}

class Page2State extends State<Page2> {

  refreshList(){
   //this function refreshes the list
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
           child: ListView.builder(
             //some child widgets here
           )
        )
     );

   }
}
```

Edit: Edited my code. Turns out I have to navigate to page2 tab first, because when I am in page 1, page 2 is not mounted to the screen. So i added a pageController and navigate to page2 first.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is that you are not injecting the key in you Page2 instance when using it, thats why the currentState in null.
Usually when i want to achieve this, i use the key attribute like so

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  static final GlobalKey<Page2State> staticGlobalKey =
      new GlobalKey<Page2State>();

  Page2() : super(key: Page2.currentStateKey); // Key injection
  @override
  Page2State createState() => Page2State();
}

class Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  refreshList() {

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
                //some child widgets here
                )));
  }
}
```

then to call the refreshList() from anywhere in your app just do

```
Page2.staticGlobalKey.currentState.refreshList();
```

You could work around and use another approach instead of static key, but this should be a working solution.

Comment: Sorry, if i understand correctly, the currentStateKey in the named parameters here is not staticGlobalKey? So in my main parent class, I have to pass a unique key to page2?

Answer (score 0):

In `PageView`, Only one page is `mounted`(or active) at a time.

Here when you call `page2Key.currentState.refreshList();` from `Page1`, the `Page2` is currently `unmounted`(or deactive). So the state itself is null.

So you cannot do `setState` of another page.

Comment: I see, thanks! So if i understand correctly, I have to make sure that page 2 is mounted first, before calling any functions/static variables from that class.